# How to get friends of friends that have the same interest?

Tags: neo4j, gremlin

Getting friends of friend are pretty easy, I got this which seems to work great.

```
g.v(1).in('FRIEND').in('FRIEND').filter{it != g.v(1)}
```

But what I want to do is only get friends of friends that have the same interests. Below I want Joe to be suggested Moe but not Noe because they do not have the same interest.

[image: Drawing of graph]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to extend your gremlin traversal to go over the LIKES edges too:

```
g.v(1).in('FRIEND').in('FRIEND').filter{it != g.v(1)}.dedup() \
       as('friend').in('LIKES').out('LIKES').filter{it == g.v(1)}. \
       back('friend').dedup()
```

Basically this goes out to friends of friends, as you had before and saves the position in the pipe under the name `friend`. It then goes out to mutual likes and searches for the original
source node. If it finds one it jumps back `friend`. The `dedup()` just removes duplicates and may speed up traversals.

The directionality of this may not be 100% correct as you haven't indicated direction of edges in your diagram.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add arrows, that would have helped. In my model FRIEND is bi-directional and LIKE starts with the User node and ends with the Language one. So this worked: g.v(1).in('FRIEND').in('FRIEND').filter{it != g.v(1)}.dedup().as('fof').out('LIKES').in('LIKES').filter{it == g.v(1)}.back('fof').dedup()

Answer (score 2):

Does this have to be in Gremlin? If Cypher is acceptable, you can do:

```
START s=node(Joe)
MATCH s-[:FRIEND]-()-[:FRIEND]-fof, s-[:LIKES]-()-[:LIKES]-fof
WHERE s != fof
RETURN fof
```

Comment: I'm using the neo4jClient so I can try this if I can't get the other one to work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Query to get Mutual friends without considering common likes,
But if you they have common likes it will come on top. 
Take a look of Order by.

```
    MATCH (me:User{userid:'34219'}) 
    MATCH (me)-[:FRIEND]-()-[:FRIEND]-(potentialFriend)
    WITH me, potentialFriend,  COUNT(*) AS friendsInCommon
    WITH me,
         potentialFriend,
         SIZE((potentialFriend)-[:LIKES]->()<-[:LIKES]-(me)) AS sameInterest, 
         friendsInCommon
    WHERE NOT (me)-[:FRIEND]-(potentialFriend)
    RETURN potentialFriend, sameInterest, friendsInCommon, 
    friendsInCommon + sameInterest AS score
    ORDER BY score DESC;
```

If you want only common likes add foll. condition -

```
Where sameInterest>0
```